# Django convert string into model for form

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a simple reusable Django app which links into the User model but since this can be replaced I need to link it into `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

This is fine within `models` but I have a formset based on the `User` so I need a form which I'm trying to populate as follows:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from optin.models import UserOptin
from django.conf import settings
#from django.contrib.auth.models import User
USER_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', None) or \
             'auth.User'

class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = USER_MODEL
        fields = '__all__'


class UserOptinForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserOptin
        fields = '__all__'

UserOptinFormSet = inlineformset_factory(USER_MODEL, UserOptin,
form=UserOptinForm, extra=0)
```

This generates an error:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

This is because `USER_MODEL` is a string.  How do I convert it into the actual `model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval()` function, all expressions argument parsed inside will be evaluated as a Python expression [More info can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

```
USER_MODEL = eval(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', None) or 'auth.User') 
# The fallback will raise an Error here
```

I suggest that you import `User` from `django.contrib.auth.models`
Because, if `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is not defined, the fallback will be `auth.User`, it will raise `NameError` no module name `auth`, so you may use the following

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
USER_MODEL = eval(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', None) or 'User')
```

Comment: this looks promising but gives me `NameError: name 'auth' is not defined`

Comment: which option that you choose? the seconds is the one that you shoud use, because there'is no module 'auth' imported

Comment: The second is the option I chose

Comment: what is the value of `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings.py

Comment: I thing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is `auth.User` in your settings.py that's why you have this error. when eval() tries to convert it, it actually doesn't find the `auth` package